# What has changed in sqlite3 so that the query plan does not show the estimated number of rows anymore?

Tags: indexing, sqlite, query-planner

In version 3.7.8 the query plan looked like

```
SCAN TABLE Cities (~1000000 rows)
SEARCH TABLE PostalCodes USING INTEGER PRIMARY KEY (rowid=?) (~1 rows)
```

but with 3.8.10.2 it is

```
SCAN TABLE Cities
SEARCH TABLE PostalCodes USING COVERING INDEX sqlite_autoindex_PostalCodes_1 (PostalCode=?)
```

What has changed? Can I somehow configure that it shows the estimated number of rows again?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What has changed is that the query planner was rewritten.
During that, the printing of the number of rows was removed.

This cannot be reconfigured.